# Difficulties in algebraic simplifications

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am a new user, and I am a bit puzzled while experimenting with *Mathematica* functions, their derivatives and derivatives of functions.

I have an expression such as:

```
x^(-4 - m[x])*(6*m[x] + x*(x^3*h1[x_]^4 + 6*x^3*h1[x_]^2*
      Derivative[1][h1][x_] + 3*x^3*Derivative[1][h1][x_]^2 - 
     8*Derivative[1][m][x] + 6*x*Derivative[2][m][x] - 
     4*h1[x_]*(2*m[x] + 3*x*(-Derivative[1][m][x] + 
         x*Derivative[2][m][x]))))
```

and I try to simplify using:

```
/.   -((2*m[x])/x^3) + (3*Derivative[1][m][x])/x^2 - 
    (3*Derivative[2][m][x])/x -> Derivative[2][h1][x]
```

But it seems impossible to replace the algebraic terms with the
function `h1''[x]`.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Try something like: `Derivative[2][m][x] -> x * Derivative[2][h1][x] / 3 + ((2*m[x])/x^3) - (3*Derivative[1][m][x])/x^2`.  I think there's a duplicate somewhere on site about substituting algebraic expressions, if someone can find it.

Comment: It is not quite clear, what do you want to achieve, but before all you should remove errors replacing numerous  `x_`s in your expression by `x `s. Then a good idea might be to precisely explain, what term do you want to get rid off: there always exists a way for that.

Comment: Sorry I tried to make no mistakes using cut and paste and it seems it did not work completely... so, again, suppose an expression:

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I apologize for not being able to write correctly the "expr"'s.  I cut back the original expression to my notebook and is correct.. but not the function I wanted to extract from the "expre". The point is that I want to replace some of the terms by a function (h1'[x]) but it does not work.. I  changed x_s by x s.. I uses different other commands... but when the expression is simple (few terms) mathematica is able to find the replacement but no when is a long expression and you use many "assumptions" in FullSimplify .Thanks again for you help and time.

Comment: @user35679 First, below your post you can find a hyperlink "edit". Click on it and introduce the corrections into your code by removing `_` where it does not belong. Its an error. Second, you did not understand my question. I see, what combination you want to replace by `h''[x]`. My point is that you may want to remove a term of a special form from your expression, or otherwise from a certain place of your expression. For example, if you need to get rid of `m''[x]` you should operate according to the advice of MichaelE2 above. But may be, you need something else, it is not quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = x^(-4 - m[x])*(6*m[x] + 
          x*(x^3*h1[x]^4 + 6*x^3*h1[x]^2*
                 Derivative[1][h1][x] + 
               3*x^3*Derivative[1][h1][x]^
                   2 - 8*Derivative[1][m][
                   x] + 6*x*Derivative[2][m][
                   x] - 4*h1[x_]*(2*m[x] + 
                    3*x*(-Derivative[1][m][
                            x] + x*Derivative[2][m][
                            x]))));
```

Keeep the LHS of the replacement rule as simple as possible, e.g., m''[x] -> ...

```
expr2 = Simplify[expr /. 
       Solve[-((2*m[x])/x^3) + 
               (3*Derivative[1][m][x])/
                 x^2 - (3*Derivative[2][m][
                      x])/x == Derivative[2][
                 h1][x], Derivative[2][m][
             x]][[1]]]

(*  x^(-4 - m[x])*(x^4*h1[x]^4 + 
      2*m[x] + 6*x^4*h1[x]^2*
        Derivative[1][h1][x] + 
      3*x^4*Derivative[1][h1][x]^2 - 
      2*x*Derivative[1][m][x] - 
      2*x^3*Derivative[2][h1][x] + 
      4*x^4*h1[x_]*Derivative[2][h1][
          x])  *)
```

Comment: It Works!.. Thank you very much to solve this question that was posted so unclear...  What I have read in books and manuals is that simplification is not easy (or straightforward...) so there are several approaches when the direct "Simplify" does not work (this include "Expand", "Factor", rules with -assumptions- etc..) however I am not sure I have read about this workaround....That is to say, to use the -function- you want to collect and solve it in terms of one of its members, I guess it should be possible to use other -unknow-such as -m'[x]- and it will also work.   Very nice workaround!!